# How to get Hostname and Port of IBM MobileFirst server where a Java Adapter is deployed?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0.0. I have a Java Adapter that is deployed on the mobilefirst server that is calling an external service. After creating a resource on the external system, I return the created id on “location” response header. It gives me the complete url of the created resource of the external system like http://example.com:1234/resource_name/1234

I don’t want to expose the external system’s url to the caller / client of my adapter. I want to return something like this - http://mobilefirstserver.com:6789/mfp/api/adapters/MyAdapter/resource_name/1234

where "mobilefirstserver" is the server on which MyAdapter is running. I am unable to find any method from mfp libraries where it can retrieve “mobilefirstserver” and “6789”. I can retrieve the adapter’s target URI, which is “example” and “1234” from adapter.xml, but not the host and port details of the mobilefirst server.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

1. Use the configuration API to obtain it: `ConfigurationAPI.getServerJNDIProperty("mfpadmin/mfp.admin.‌​authorization.server‌​.url")` - this will be something like this: http://localhost:9080/mfp/api. You will need to extract the host and port from it.
2. You could use, on the client-side, the `WL.App.getServerUrl` API and use it as a parameter in your call to the adapter. But that little sense for your scenario (although I didn't fully 'get' what is the scenario).
3. Since the server is yours, you can simply hard-code these values in your adapter implementation.

Comment: Thanks Idan. I am using ConfigurationAPI..getServerJNDIProperty("mfpadmin/mfp.admin.authorization.server.url") to get the mobilefirst server host and port. Is that fine ?

Comment: Note however that you will need to extract the host and port from it.

Comment: I have similar requirement but I am getting ConfigurationAPI.getServerJNDIProperty("mfpadmin/mfp.admin.‌​authorization.server‌​.url") as **null**. I am using @Context
 ConfigurationAPI configApi;

I am using devKit mobilefirst server and also didn't set any properties manually.